Why does the r-package/function `plm` report a z-statistic for a random effects model and a t-statistic for a fixed effects model?
Taking examples from the help file on package plm,
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")
wi <- plm(inv ~ value + capital,
          data = Grunfeld, model = "within", effect = "twoways")
swar <- plm(inv ~ value + capital,
            data = Grunfeld, model = "random", effect = "twoways")
summary(wi)

gives output
Twoways effects Within Model

Call:
plm(formula = inv ~ value + capital, data = Grunfeld, effect = "twoways", 
    model = "within")

Balanced Panel: n = 10, T = 20, N = 200

Residuals:
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-162.6094  -19.4710   -1.2669   19.1277  211.8420 

Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
value   0.117716   0.013751  8.5604 6.653e-15 ***
capital 0.357916   0.022719 15.7540 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    1615600
Residual Sum of Squares: 452150
R-Squared:      0.72015
Adj. R-Squared: 0.67047
F-statistic: 217.442 on 2 and 169 DF, p-value: < 2.22e-16

And
summary(swar)

gives
Twoways effects Random Effect Model 
   (Swamy-Arora's transformation)

Call:
plm(formula = inv ~ value + capital, data = Grunfeld, effect = "twoways", 
    model = "random")

Balanced Panel: n = 10, T = 20, N = 200

Effects:
                  var std.dev share
idiosyncratic 2675.43   51.72 0.274
individual    7095.25   84.23 0.726
time             0.00    0.00 0.000
theta: 0.864 (id) 0 (time) 0 (total)

Residuals:
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-177.1700  -19.7576    4.6048   19.4676  252.7596 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z-value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -57.865377  29.393359 -1.9687  0.04899 *  
value         0.109790   0.010528 10.4285  < 2e-16 ***
capital       0.308190   0.017171 17.9483  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    2376000
Residual Sum of Squares: 547910
R-Squared:      0.7694
Adj. R-Squared: 0.76706
Chisq: 657.295 on 2 DF, p-value: < 2.22e-16

So the (simple) question is, why does the plm summary report the t-statistics for tests of parameters for the fixed effects (i.e., "within") model, and z-statistics for those of a random effects model? I suspect it's a simple arbitrary inconsistency of presentation, but I am interested to know if there is a deeper reason.

Welcome to CV. I saw your question on Stack Overflow, where it was closed for being about statistics, and here it might be closed due to being too programming-focused (because you're asking about a specific package). Degrees of freedom in mixed models, and testing random effects in general, is not a settled topic; have a look at this FAQ and its links for some more background (not specifically about plm, I don't know what model that fits).

@PBulls - My question is essentially, Is there something about the fixed effects model that, differently from the random effects model, makes t the more appropriate statistic to report -- convergence in T rather than nT or something. I suspect the answer is "no", so that it's just some arbitrary inconsistency in the software package. So, in that sense, you could say that whether or not my question is about software or statistics sort is the essence of the question itself! (If someone suggests taking it to https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/, I will not be amused.)

I believe the answer still lies in what is discussed in my links above: outside of the linear model (this also includes GLMs), degrees of freedom -- which are required to use t rather than Z -- aren't defined in a clear way that most agree on; in the best case competing approximation methods exist and sometimes none do. Wald statistics are in that case a lazy default, though I'm sure many would agree that t would be better if we knew how to calculate $\nu$. More commonly profile likelihood or score methods (or permutation/resampling) are used as alternatives to Z-based inference however.

@PBulls -- I don't think you have mentioned anything that motivates treating one model differently that the other, have you?

Then I suggest you read again; the first model appears to be a regular LM so df are well-defined, the second not so.

It is not specific to plm. For example, Stata (see e.g., http://www.stata.com/manuals14/xtxtreg.pdf, p. 17 (example 4)) and gretl do the same.
Note also that the Wald test for the coefficients to be jointly 0 in summary (can be output separately as well by pwaldtest) is based on an F statistic for FE models while it is chi-square-based for RE models due to the same reason.
Literature reference addressing this particular difference seem scarce but here is one about FE vs. RE treatment in OLS-based panel data models (where the mentioned GLS estimator is the RE model and the T and F statistics refer to the FE model):
Andreß/Golsch/Schmidt (2013), Applied Panel Data Analysis for Economic
and Social Surveys, Springer, Heidelberg et al., p. 156-157:

With respect to test statistics, we have to keep in mind that the
statistical properties of GLS estimators (consistency, efficiency) are
only valid where large samples are used. Therefore, instead of T and F
tests, we have to use the normal and the chisquare distribution.
Testing single parameters is possible using the Z statistic, which is
normally distributed. Linear restrictions on a set of parameters can
be tested with a so-called Wald statistic X2,2 , which is χ2
distributed. The Z statistic is computed exactly like the T statistic,
only the test distribution is the normal instead of the T
distribution. To compute the Wald statistic manually, you need matrix
algebra. Basically, the Wald statistic is a weighted sum of all the
differences between the tested parameters and the corresponding
parameters assumed in the null hypothesis. These differences are
weighted with the estimated variances and covariances of the estimated
parameters (see Sect. 7.2.1). Statistical programs for RE estimation
will automatically compute this statistic for you.

The linked Stata manual puts about the Wald test for an RE model (on p. 18):

All that is known about the random-effects estimator is its asymptotic
properties, so rather than reporting an F statistic for overall
significance, xtreg, re reports a χ2.


When both a mean and a standard deviation are estimated from data in a fixed-effects regression under usual assumptions with errors following a normal distribution, the coefficient estimates have a t distribution. See this Wikipedia entry, for example. With an underlying normal distribution, the estimates of the mean and the variance are independent. The t distribution then best describes the uncertainty in the coefficient estimates.
I don't know how plm() handles random-effect models, but the authors of the package evidently do not think that the t distribution adequately describes the distribution of the fixed-effect coefficient estimates, given the need to estimate the fixed and random effects together. They presumably are assuming asymptotic normality of the coefficient estimates (thus following the z distribution), similarly to the situation with generalized linear models, survival models, etc. As your example is from a vignette distributed with the package, that's unlikely to be an "arbitrary inconsistency of presentation."
